# Merging Cells with Apache POI for PowerPoint (HSLF)

Tags: java, apache, powerpoint, apache-poi

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to merge cells using Table/TableCell for Powerpoint (like colspan in HTML), similar to this example for Excel http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#MergedCells

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Merging table cells is supported as of POI version 3.8:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52658

Answer (score 0):

Merge the cells in powerpoint, then save the pptx, then unzip it and inspect the result.

You can then do the same programmatically using POI or pptx4j